# boost condition needs volatile variables

Tags: c++, boost-thread

Hy,

I have started working with threads in C++ (boost threads),
and I have found my self in the following situation:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(monitor);
while (buffered == 0) {
    buffer_not_empty.wait(lk);
}
```

And I was wandering if the int variable `buffered` should be volatile. 
I would say that it should, to prevent a optimization like this, at compile time:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(monitor);
while (true) {
    buffer_not_empty.wait(lk);
}
```

but since this is a example from the boost documentation, I may be missing something...

is a lock/mutex/condition enough to prevent this kind of optimizations ? like in java ?

Comment: The `monitor` lock protects the variable. That's enough.

Comment: this means that things are just like in java, any lock will protect the variables

Comment: Indeed, any lock protects all variables consistently accessed under that lock. C++11 will also give you lockless variables via the atomic types, but AFAIR boost does not provide them, though it in fact does have them for at least some types in the details namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not mess with `volatile`. `volatile` has absolutely nothing to do with multithreading. Even if the compiler doesn't optimize things away to the loop you mention somehow, your CPU might make the same optimization, and `volatile` does not affect the CPU.

`wait` should contain the necessary memory barrier instructions required make this operate as expected.

Comment: ok, thanks, I didn't manage to find any good information on this